# Weblogic10.3.5 eclipse server configuration issue

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, weblogic, weblogic11g

I successfully installed weblogic11(10.3.5) on my machine. But when I am trying to configure weblogic server in eclipse Ganymede, I am getting "The path "C:\bea1\wlserver_10.3" does not contain a valid WebLogic Server install." This path is correct but where I am going wrong. Do I have any suggestion ?

Comment: Weblogic10.3.5 is not Weblogic11.

Comment: have a look [Oracle-Base](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/11g/oracle-weblogic-server-11gr1-1035-installation-on-windows.php)

Comment: +1 I apologize, but I will never understand Oracle marketing.

Answer (score 2):

You should first switch to a newer version of Eclipse and Oracle Tools. Ganymede is four years out of date. If after the switch, you are still seeing problems, we can look into it further.

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/eclipse/downloads/index.html